# Number set with induction

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction

let $a_n$ be defined as :

$a_0 = a_1 = 1$

$a_n = 2a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}  ,  n<=2$

prove that every *n* ∈ *N* U {0} , $a_n$ will be odd

I tried to prove it with induction, but got stuck and couldn't continue

**Base checks:**
n=2: $a_n=2a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} = 2a_1 + a_0 = 3$

n=3: $a_n=2a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} = 2a_2 + a_1 = 6+1=7$

**Assume for n :** $a_n=2*(2k+1)+(2k+1)$

**Show for n+1** :$a_{n+1}=2a_{n+1-1}+a_{n+1-2}=2a_n+a_{n-1}=2*(2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})+a_{n-1}=4a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}
+a_{n-1}=3a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}$

Looking forward for your help

Comment: You already know it's true for $n=0,1$ which can be used as the base case. Given it's true for $n=k,k+1$ then $a_{k+2}=2a_{k+1}+a_k$ is odd because it's the sum of an even and odd number. So $a_n$ is odd for all $n\ge0$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to check $n=2$ or $n=3$. You already have the base cases. Just observe that $2x+y$ is odd if $y$ is odd. However, it's the term two steps lower, in your case, so the idea is to use *complete induction*.

The cases $n=0$ and $n=1$ are true by assumption.

Suppose the statement holds for every $m<n$, where $n>2$ (this is the complete induction hypothesis). Then
$$
a_{n}=2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}
$$
Since $2a_{n-1}$ is even and $a_{n-2}$ is odd (by induction hypothesis), also $a_n$ is odd.

Alternatively, you can observe that $a_{n+2}\equiv a_{n}\pmod{2}$. So you can prove by simple induction that $a_{2m}\equiv 1\pmod{2}$ and $a_{2m+1}\equiv 1\pmod{2}$; thus every even- an odd-indexed term is odd.